# Show texture or delete shader of a circle area on click, Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, mask, texture-mapping

a Unity question here:

I am trying to show an area of the screen on click like a circle. I have uploaded a very simple image to show what I mean.. but I am having trouble to do so, I have tried playing around with shaders but the onclick just changes the whole texture back to normal...

[image: map example]

Just to explain the image, when someone clicks the section of the cube it will reveal the texture as shown above. it is a 3d world but shown in a 2d plane, so if someone clicks the edge of the cube the other side will be colored as well. So I thought about just making a canvas but wouldn't look smooth.

If there is anyone that can help me with this that would be great either shaders, canvas or anything. Preferably in C#/shader.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 2 Gameobject 1 is with cutout and the other doesn't.

code for the button

```
using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;



public class HideAndShow: MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject Object1Cut, Object2NoCut;
  void Start(){
     //This will show the default
     Object1Cut.SetActive(false);
     Object2NoCut.SetActive(true);
  }
  public void ObjectWithCutout(){
     Object1Cut.SetActive(true);
     Object2NoCut.SetActive(false);
  }
  public void ObjectWithNoCut(){
     Object1Cut.SetActive(false);
     Object2NoCut.SetActive(true);
  }
}
```